# Thiessen Polygon - geotools

Tags: geotools, voronoi-thiessen

I need to create Thiessen Polygon from a point collection and then intercept them with other polygons.

I need to do this from a java program.

I'm using the [Geotools](http://www.geotools.org/) library. I was able to load the points from a .shp file.

I found this https://github.com/mapplus/spatial_statistics_for_geotools_udig
but I can't find any documentation on how to use the [ThiessenPolygonProcess class](https://github.com/mapplus/spatial_statistics_for_geotools_udig/blob/7c834e1376d3ad583a2a0e567b4a3129a83ad73f/GeoTools/process-spatialstatistics/src/main/java/org/geotools/process/spatialstatistics/ThiessenPolygonProcess.java)

How can I create thisen polygons?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can do it, after all it was much easier

```
SimpleFeatureCollection poligonos =ThiessenPolygonProcess.process(coleccionDePuntos,ThiessenAttributeMode.All, null , null);
```